# Prove either $I$ or $J$ is contained in $P$. Understanding the statement of the question.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

I am trying to prove this question:

Assume $R$ is commutative. Let $I$ and $J$ be ideals of $R$ and assume $P$ is a prime ideal of $R$ that contains $IJ$
(for example, if $P$ contains $I \cap J$). Prove either $I$ or $J$ is contained in $P$.

**But I do not understand what is the relation of the prime ideal $P$ being containing $IJ$ and giving example of that by $P$ containing $I \cap J$ (what is the relation between the 2 ideals $IJ$ and $I \cap J$)** could someone explain this to me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We always have $IJ \subset I\cap J$, so $I\cap J \subset P \implies IJ \subset P$.

Comment: Is there a proof that $IJ \subset I \cap J$? Is there a proof for $I \cap J \subset P$?

Comment: @Brain $IJ$ consists of sums of elements of the form $ij$ for $i\in I$ and $j\in J$.  Since $I$ and $J$ are ideals, $ij\in I$ and $ij\in J$, in other words $ij\in I\cap J$.